# Cassandra nodetool removenode hangs

Tags: cassandra, nodetool

I was trying to remove a dead node from one of cassandra(version 2.1.6) seed node's  using ( I only ran from one seed node)
.

> /nodetool removenode NodeID

But it hangs for too long , `/nodetool removenode status`

> RemovalStatus: Removing token (-9171133960945511267). Waiting for
>   replication confirmation from [/x.x.x.x,/x.x.x.x,/x.x.x.x,/x.x.x.x].

using CTRL-C I stopped the command

but then when I try to run

> ./nodetool removenode force NodeID

It says

```
 error: This node is already processing a removal. Wait for it to complete, or use 'removenode force' if this has failed.
-- StackTrace --
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This node is already processing a removal. Wait for it to complete, or use 'removenode force' if this has failed.
```

What is the usual course of action such that my cluster is not impacted in anyway.

Answer (score 6):

It was my mistake I had to run

> ./nodetool removenode force

Without NodeID at the end. and It solved the issue.

Comment: This 'hanging' is a well-known and still open bug in cassandra. See: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-6542